# How to align two lightning components side by side?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, fileupload

I have a `fileUpload` in my aura:component, and I want to diplay a `formattedUrl` next to it on the same line. This is the code I have used:

```
<div>
    <span><lightning:input aura:id="photoLoader" label="Entity/Health Coach Photo" onchange="{!c.handleDoctorFilesChange}" type="file" name="photoLoader" accept="{!v.filetype}" multiple="false"/></span>
    <span><lightning:formattedUrl value="https://salesforce.com" label="Visit salesforce.com" target="_blank" /></span>
</div>
```

and this is the result I got:

[image]

I want this 'Visit salesforce.com' on the left side of the `fileUpload` in the same line, close to it. I have tried many approaches and nothing worked. Anyone please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `lightning:layout`:

```
<lightning:layout>
    <lightning:layoutItem size="6">
        <lightning:input aura:id="photoLoader" label="Entity/Health Coach Photo" onchange="{!c.handleDoctorFilesChange}" type="file" name="photoLoader" accept="{!v.filetype}" multiple="false"/>
    </lightning:layoutItem>
    <lightning:layoutItem size="6">
        <lightning:formattedUrl value="https://salesforce.com" label="Visit salesforce.com" target="_blank" />
    </lightning:layoutItem>
</lightning:layout>
```

Other alternatives are possible as well, such as using a flex layout to minimize the space used, or altering the size for each item.

You can also fix the problem by making the surrounding span an inline-block.

```
    <span style="display: inline-block">
        <lightning:input aura:id="photoLoader" label="Entity/Health Coach Photo" onchange="{!c.handleDoctorFilesChange}" type="file" name="photoLoader" accept="{!v.filetype}" multiple="false"/>
    </span>
    <span style="display: inline-block">
        <lightning:formattedUrl value="https://salesforce.com" label="Visit salesforce.com" target="_blank" />
    </span>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But, I have tried it before. It is creating a big gap between the fileUpload and link. I want the link to be next to fileUpload

Comment: @JayeshBabu Added another alternative you could use.

Comment: thanks very much. second approach worked.